# transaction management using spring jdbc in liferay

Tags: spring, transactions, liferay, spring-jdbc, jta

I need to implement JTA transaction management using spring jdbc in liferay. I have two databases connected in liferay using jndi. In my project I am doing jdbc CRUD operation using jdbc spring dao and for liferay, it is through liferay build-in service api. For any exception, rollback is working fine for other db but it is not working for liferay.

Below is my code sample:
In portal-ext.prop I have defined

```
transaction.management.impl= <JTATransactionmanager>
```

In my project's context.xml of tomcat I have defined user transaction as mentioned at liferay's site :
**context.xml**

```
`<Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction" />
<Transaction factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="600" /><br>
<Resource auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.objectweb.jotm.datasource.DataSourceFactory" driverClassName="<postgresqldriver>" name="jdbc/LiferayPool" username="root" password="" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useFastDateParsing=false" />}}}<br>

<Resource auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.objectweb.jotm.datasource.DataSourceFactory" driverClassName="<postgresqldriver>" name="jdbc/test" username="root" password="" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useFastDateParsing=false" />}}}
```

`
In bean.xml of my project :

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>


<beans:bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/test"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
```

**in my class**:

```
@Transactional(rollback{myexception.class})
public void test()
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all put an eye on [this discussion](http://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/22309094).

What you wouldn't forget is that Liferay rollbacks both for PortalException or SystemException... but it rollbacks only the beans injected inside the current transaction context.

This means that you shouldn't use XLocalServiceUtil, but the injected xLocalService bean.
To get it you need to advice your service layer by service.xml declarations or, inside your serviceImpl class, by adding and referring to:

```
@BeanReference(type=XArticleLocalService.class)
protected XArticleLocalService xArticleLocalService;
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Actually I am doing transaction in two different databases. first one is liferay's database for which I am using liferay's api and for other one I am using spring-jdbc not custom service. I have defined rollback for a custom exception, But when it that exception throws the rollback is happening for other databse not for liferay.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what is the way in which methods calls each others... (eg. does your service layer calls "custom" methods code, or vice versa?)

Comment: I have one service class and it has one method. This method is first calling liferay servcie to create records in liferay database and then calling spring-jdbc template to create record in other db. I have annotate this method as @Transactional(rollback={exception}).

Comment: I'm afraid that they aren't running in the same Spring context... and so in the same transactional context (and LR service methods, exiting from their own context, perform a commit). Can you verify that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the XXXServiceUtil.java. Whenever you use ServiceUtil, any method you call executes under a **different transaction manager** (regardless of current thread transaction state) as it's a completely **different class loader**. Remember in Liferay, every portlet/plugin has its own class loader.